# I am getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: testing, karate, bdd

I am currently using karate version 0.9.6
I am using Java SDK 17
And when I tried to run my tests I see the below error.

```
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.intuit.karate.Runner$Builder.tagSelector(Runner.java:80)
at com.intuit.karate.Runner.parallel(Runner.java:309)
at com.intuit.karate.Runner$Builder.parallel(Runner.java:190)
at com.intuit.karate.cli.Main.main(Main.java:59)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke     "javax.script.ScriptEngine.createBindings()" because "com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.NASHORN" is null
at com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.createBindings(ScriptBindings.java:159)
at com.intuit.karate.core.Tags.<init>(Tags.java:158)
at com.intuit.karate.core.Tags.<clinit>(Tags.java:48)
... 5 more`
```

Comment: I have also tried stesp as mentioned in https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide#breaking-changes

removed dependency
 testImplementation('com.intuit.karate:karate-apache:0.9.6.RC4')

and using

Comment: Vijay - you are using a very very old version of karate that is not supported. you have to upgrade

Comment: which version do you recommend? I tried using version 1.0.1 and see this issue is fixed, but see new issue

>>>> js failed:
01: read('classpath:src/test/java/util/basic-auth.js')
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: not found: src/test/java/util/basic-auth.js

Comment: I tried upgrading the version to 1.1.0 and result is same as above

Comment: Finally was able to solved the issue
By upgrading the karate version to 1.1.0

**Note:**

Fixed the issue as well
**>>>> js failed: 01: read('classpath:src/test/java/util/basic-auth.js') <<<< org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: not found: src/test/java/util/basic-auth.js**

Added the files src/test/java/* to classpath
And the code was updated to 
**read('classpath:util/basic-auth.js')**

Doing this works like a charm!